# Crawling FBA Host Named Site Collection

Tags: crawling

I need to be able to crawl a host named site collection with FBA.

I have disableloopbackcheck set, permissions set, and the web application extended into classic authentication, however I am getting "access denied" errors when trying to crawl the HNSC.

I can successfully crawl other site collections inside the web app, just not the HNSC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
Enable NTLM windows authentication on the web app, remove the web app extension.

Change the default log in page from /_login/default.aspx to /_forms/default.aspx. And voila, it crawls correctly and still defaults to the FBA log in page.